# Converting CSV data to a list of objects Javascript

Tags: javascript

I wish to convert a CSV file with data on camping spots to a list of objects. The attributes of the shelters are separated by a semicolon and looks something like this:

```
X;Y;postnumber_city;name;postnumber;describtion_short;max_number_of_people

445502.7247;6212415.4577;Hvide Sande;Shelter 1;6960;3 shelters, grillplads, borde-/bænkesæt og toilet;6
```

My code looks like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function csvToObjects(fileName) {
    fs.readFileSync(fileName, "utf-8");
    let jsObj = [];
    let shelters = fileName.split('\n')
    for (let attributes of shelters) {
        attributes = shelters.split('; ');
    }
    obj.push(attributes)
}


console.log(csvToObjects('shelters.csv'));
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. I get an error from      attributes = shelters.split('; ');

TypeError: shelters.split is not a function

Comment: `obj.push(attributes)` inside `for loop`

Comment: You are also splitting on `'; '` (with a space), which doesn't match the data in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `obj.push(attributes)` inside `for` loops,and use `attributes.split('; ');` instead of `shelters.split('; ')`

```
function csvToObjects(fileName) {
    fs.readFileSync(fileName, "utf-8");
    let jsObj = [];
    let shelters = fileName.split('\n')
    for (let attributes of shelters) {
        let data = attributes.split(';');
        jsObj.push(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i keep getting an error: 
TypeError: shelters.split is not a function

Comment: I see, but now it states that data is not defined with a reference error. Is this because I use readFileSync instead of readFile?

Comment: @NikolajBejder using `jsObj` instead of `obj`,you need to check your code carefully,there are some variable using invalid

Answer (score 0):

I attempted with some other for-loops and assigned a variable for my readfile, which seemed to do the job.

```
const fs = require('fs');

function csvToObjects(fileName) {
    let file = fs.readFileSync(fileName, "utf-8");
    let jsObj = [];
    let shelters = file.split('\n')
    let attributes = shelters[0].split(';')
    for (let i = 0; i < shelters.length; i++) {
        let data = shelters[i].split(';')
        let obj = {};
        for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            obj[attributes[j].trim()] = data[j].trim();
        }
        jsObj.push(obj);
    }
    return jsObj;
}
```